# relative div is not wraping its absolute content... Anyone know the solution?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, responsiveness

I am trying to place a responsive absolute positioned image inside of a relative div. I have placed the border around two dives to visualize the issue. The one on the right doesn't wrap. Also, I would like to keep image navigation in the middle of an image.

The main goal is to keep wrapping div responsive and with the size of the wrapped image - when the image size changes on window resize.

Here you can see the issue in codepen - http://codepen.io/GlupiJas/pen/PwrLbb

---

[image]

**advert.css**

```
body{

}
.wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 100px auto;
}
.advert{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.advert img{
    position: absolute;
}

.advert button{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.advert:hover button{
    visibility: visible;
}

.advert button#advertCloseButton{
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
.advert button#advertNextButton{
    bottom:50%;
    left:0px;
}
.advert button#advertPreviousButton{
    bottom:50%;
    right:0px;
}
.advert button#advertStopButton{
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
.advert button#advertPlayButton{
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}

.border{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstarp 3 Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstarp 3 Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstarp 3 Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="advert.css">
    <script src="js/advert.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 border">
        .col-xs-12 .col-md-8
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 border">
        <div class="advert">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="" width="100%">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="" width="100%">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x300.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="" width="100%">
            <button id="advertCloseButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
            <button id="advertNextButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">></button>
            <button id="advertPreviousButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><</button>
            <button id="advertStopButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">pause</button>
            <button id="advertPlayButton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">play</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
$(function(){
    advert({
        closeButton: true,
        navButton: true,
        timeToShow: 100,
        timeDelay: 1000,
        timeToFade: 100
    }); 
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: When you absolutely position an element, it is taken out of the document flow and it will not affect the dimensions of its parent(s). Perhaps absolute positioning is not what you should be looking at to achieve that particular layout?

Comment: Perhaps or ... could I use javascript/jQuery to determin it actual size in some interwal that will keep checking for an size of the image bing change and change the size of a wraping div respectivly ?

Comment: It is possible, but you might want to rethink what do you actually want to achieve with the layout. Are you trying to create an image slider of sorts for the adverts? Using JS is possible but is unnecessarily complicated, because remember that your image dimensions are responsive, so you will have to recalculate the height every single time the viewport is resized.

Comment: Two approaches are possible, either height:100% or height in percentages which needs to be set to each parent container starting from the top <html> or set a fixed height to the image container.

Comment: If i set fixed height on the image i will lose the resposivnes - which I dont want to.

Comment: Sure, then look at my answer. Maybe on that particular page, you can try to use a full 100% height approach. Let me know if my answer helped you out :)

Answer (score 0):

I quickly mocked up a demo but the issue you are having is more because you have many divs added (one added div for the border and some other too which are not needed - therefore i had to set height:100% to each one of them) and no height set for the container of all your images and buttons.

So sure, `position:relative;` to parent and `position:absolute;` to its children will work if the container has a height set and will make sure your play buttons are contained in the same div.

In this demo, I quickly set the height to all parent containers to height:100%; to show you how the height does affect the issue.

**Note** To have `height:100%` working then each parent needs to have a height fixed set or each parent starting from html,body needs to have 100% height.

You can solve your issue if you add a fixed height to the container or if you set html,body as 100% height and then make sure all children have 100% too.

**DEMO**
http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/RNzvmw

Comment: Thx for the code but in your solution after resizing the windows buttons and navigation don't stick to image but stay on the same positioin in the wraper which holds it size. Container have to be responsive regarding the image size too.

Comment: You are welcome. Bear in mind that to build a fully working solution which is fully responsive can take time. There are several approaches depending of what kind of content you want to accomodate. For instance if you need to keep the aspect ratio of the img if the img is not square. I was just pointing out an approach then you can fix it with media queries and checking the width of each column used since you are using bootstrap...

Comment: I agree. I want to make it work independent from the content size. Look what would it look like if the image size would be random
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emwxqr

Comment: If you have this issue then you have to change the img CSS properties.
http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/myZoVV

Comment: Cause if you need to take care of all possible aspect ratios, then it will be trickier... :)